# How to update book title?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

ok.. i'm having trouble with updating new book title.. i've already searched for solutions on this website.. and ive tried them but none of them work..

```
function update_book
{
   #echo "Title: "
   read -p $'Title: ' updatetitle
   #echo "Author: "
   read -p $'Name: ' updatename

  if grep -Fq "${updatetitle}:${updatename}" BookDB.txt
   then
      echo "Book found!"

      if ! [ -f BookDB.txt ] ; then 
touch BookDB.txt
fi

selection=0
until [ "$selection" = "f" ]; do
      echo ""
      echo ""
      echo "Book Update System"
      echo ""
      echo ""
      echo "a) Update title"
      echo "b) Update Author"
      echo "c) Update Price"
      echo "d) Update Qty Available"
      echo "e) Update Qty Sold"
      echo "f) Back to main menu"

      echo -n "Enter your option: "
      read selection
      echo ""
      case $selection in
            a) upd_title;press_enter;;
            b) upd_author;press_enter;;
            c) upd_price;press_enter;;
            d) upd_qty_avail;press_enter;;
            e) upd_qty_sold;press_enter;;
            f) main_menu;press_enter;;
            * ) tput setf 4;echo "Please enter a, b, c, d, e, or f";tput setf 7; press_enter
      esac
    done  

   else
      echo "Error!! Book does not exist!" #not found
   fi   
}
```

ok i've made some changes to the codes for this function.. found out that i should use awk to update from old to new. and use grep to get line number..so it's best i stick with this..

```
function upd_title
{
  read -p 'New title: ' title
  #awk '/liine/{ print NR; exit }' BookDB.txt
  grep -n 'regex' | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\):.*$/\1/'
  awk 'NR==n{$1=a}1' FS=":" OFS =":" n=$linenumber a = $title BookDB.txt
  echo "New title successfully updated!!"

}
```

but after i tried that code.. this is what i got:

```
Advanced Book Inventory System


1) Add new book
2) Remove existing book info
3) Update book info and quantity
4) Search for book by title/author
5) Process a book sold
6) Inventory summary report
7) Quit
Enter your option: 3

Title: The Notebook
Name: Nicholas Sparks
Book found!


    Book Update System


a) Update title
b) Update Author
c) Update Price
d) Update Qty Available
e) Update Qty Sold
f) Back to main menu
Enter your option: a

New title: Notebook
```

still doesn't update the title.. >.< anyone can help me point out what's the problem? am i missing something here

help me how to do this.. thanks! :D :D

Answer (score 0):

`$updatetitle` and `$updateauthor` defined by the `read` statements in `update_book()` are *not* visible in the `upd_title()` and other functions you define.

Try `export`ing them after they are `read` in.  If this doesn't work, pass them in as positional parameters to `update_title()`:

```
upd_title $update_title $update_author

...

function upd_title
{
    update_title=$1
    update_author=$2
    ...
}
```